# UITableViewController and UIStatusbar

Tags: ios, uitableview, uistatusbar

Scrolling in my UITableViewController with several items makes the the cell appear behind my `UIStatusBar`. I tried to do a work around using this method:

```
var bounds = self.view.bounds
    bounds.origin.y -= 20.0;
    self.view.bounds = bounds
    // Create a solid color background for the status bar



    let statusFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: -20, width: bounds.size.width, height: 20)
    let statusBar = UIView(frame: statusFrame)
    statusBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    self.view.addSubview(statusBar)
```

which will give me a red bar before scrolling. It disappears after a little bit of scrolling. I also tried to make the contentInset of the tableView top to `UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height`, but did the same.

It is important to keep the Navbar. Also my TableViewController is embedded in a `UINavigationController`

Any ideas?

Comment: What about the state when finishing scrolling, Still hide the bar or show? And what is your platform running, only iOS 8 above or all version?

Comment: ios8 and above. It needs to be solid all the time. whether scrolling or not. @ronan

Comment: You just wanna change to status bar's background color to red, and make sure it won't be changed automatically, right?

Comment: @ronan no it's not important, that it is red. It just needs to be solid/opaque so that one can't see the cells behind it.

Comment: how about `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false`?

Comment: @ronan it does make a black stripe instead of the statusbar. but the behavior seems to be good. any idea how to make this stripe white ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124196/discussion-between-ronan-and-jvs).

Answer (score 1):

One way could be, refactor UITableViewController and make it UITableView and add a top constraint below the status bar.

Another is to change the status bar color like:

```
func setStatusBarBackgroundColor(color: UIColor) {
    if let statusBar = UIApplication.sharedApplication().valueForKey("statusBarWindow")?.valueForKey("statusBar") as? UIView {
        statusBar.backgroundColor = color
    }
}
```

But be careful since it is a private api. Your app might get rejected.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use the equivalent in swift. as in using the double valueForKey

Comment: I'm getting a NSUnknownKeyException on statusBar

Comment: @JVS, kindly double check the spelling.

Answer (score 1):

According to your purpose, You could just hide the status bar.

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found an answer:

create a custom `UIView` and add it the the view of `navigationController`:

```
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width,
    height: UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height)

    let bar = UIView(frame: rect)
    bar.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    navigationController?.view.addSubview(bar)
```

works like a charm.